# massive resource consumption during mkfs.ntfs on a zvol, why (and how can I limit this)?

Tags: zfs, ntfs, multithreading, mkfs, resources

On my machine `mkfs.ntfs` is slow and results in massive use of resources, preventing me from using the machine for anything else. According to top it (or rather directly related `zvol` processes) is using 80-90% of every thread available, even threads that were already in use by other processes (such as virtual machines).

Is this massive resource use by `mkfs.ntfs` normal? And if so, is there any way to limit the number of threads that `mkfs.ntfs` uses? I am thinking that if I could limit it to just a few threads/cores, then other processes would have resources so that I can keep working.

Edit with additional info.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as my host OS, and the volume I am formatting is a ZFS zvol. This zvol shares a mirrored VDEV with an ext4 partition, off of which I run Kubuntu.

To make the zvol I ran

```
sudo zfs create -V 400G -o compression=lz4 -o volblocksize=8k -s nvme-tank/ntfs-zvol
```

After the suggestions in the comments, I tried using `nice` to de-prioritize the command. It helped a little, but still caused extreme lagginess in the VM I was using.

```
nice -n19 sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/zd16 -c 8192
```

And this is `top`. The `zvol` processes only occur during the `mkfs` command, so I assume they are directly related.:
[image: top]

Comment: You can renice the process, make it 'nicer' in the meaning that it gets lower priority so that other processes get more attention. You can do it with the command `renice` or via a tool like `htop`. A higher nice value means lower priority.

Comment: OK, looking up `renice` led to finding out about `nice`, which lets me set priority at the time of running the command. Unfortunately, running `nice -n19 mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdX` still left me unable to play music or use a VM without lagging.

Comment: Are you running several threads with subprocesses of mkfs.ntfs? Then you can try to renice each of those subprocesses. Renice works also on processes that are already running.

Comment: By the way, What computer is it (brand name and model) and in what drive (type, brand name and model) and partition size are you running mkfs.ntfs? It should not not take that long for one single case unless you tell it to zeroise the partition and check for bad sectors (and this is the default at least in my version). It is a good idea to check for bad sectors, but you can skip it with the option `-f`

Comment: Also `man ionice`. To be honest what you're seeing is very unusual. I really much doubt mkfs.ntfs may make you system (feel) slower unless there's something strange going on or it's a very weak system, i.e. some smartphone from 2010.

Comment: @sudodus This is a 16 core Threadripper and I am writing to a ZFS zvol, which itself half of a mirrored dvev made of nvmes. I should probably have mentioned that ZFS is involved in my question. But in my recollection, formatting NTFS has always been very slow compared to ext4.

Comment: `renice` and `ionice` definitely will not help considering that multiple `zvol` processes are causing a CPU hog.

Comment: OK @ArtemS.Tashkinov, you know more about this and I think you are right about renice and ionice.

Comment: The "According to top" sentence is wholly contradicted by the actual `top` output.  https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/5132

Comment: @JdeBP you are correct, I have edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: the mkfs.ntfs command will write zeros to the entire filesystem unless you use the `-f` option. That may be what is consuming so much process time. Now for my speculation: if the underlying zfs is trying to use copy-on-write but you are trying to write zeros to the entire zvol all at once, it may be trying to shuffle and organize an impossible task?

Comment: @Jeff, yes, that is the correct answer! I just ran it with `-f` and it was instantaneous. Please post this as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not not take that long for one single case unless you tell it to zeroise the partition and check for bad sectors (and this is the default at least in my version). It is a good idea to check for bad sectors, but **you can skip it with the option `-f`**

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/zd16 -c 8192
```

Answer (score 2):

NTFS formatting may be slower (e.g. it needs to write more data to initialize disk structures) than e.g. ext4 but in no ways it should make your system feel unresponsive/resources constrained.

I'm not familiar with ZFS: might it be possible that it itself hasn't yet finished its own internal tasks (synchronization, mirroring, data structures allocation etc.), or it was created using a suboptimatal configuration that's why you experience these symptoms? Or you system lacks RAM (last time I heard ZFS requires a lot more RAM to be efficient)? Your `top` output is populated with `zvol` processes which means it's the ZFS filesystem which itself is slowing your system down, not `mkfs.ntfs`.

In short we need ZFS experts here. I'm 99% sure `mkfs.ntfs` is not the culprit.

There are quite a lot of discussions on the Internet which indicate there are some ZFS intricacies you're not taking into consideration:

- https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/7631
- https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/high-100-zvol-cpu-usage-when-doing-vm-import-from-backup.57221/